# Fast Local Lookups from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a chrome extension that can do fast lookups from a fixed ~45MB dataset. The dataset is ~400k rows and I want to lookup by unique key strings.

To be clear, I don't want to serve this data over the web. I want the data to be in files that are packaged with the extension.

Options I've thought of:

1. Load it all in memory - feels like irresponsible usage for an extension, especially for lower RAM computers
2. Come up with my own storage/retrieval system with sharding and caching. Split up all the files by first letter(s), then add to an in-memory cache (backed up to disk) after each lookup - I think this would work but feels like reinventing the wheel for a hobby project, I'd rather use a well-supported framework/library.
3. Chrome docs mention a client side sql database (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/faq/#faq-dev-08). However, the link is unfortunately broken. I wasn't able to figure out what this faq is talking about, but I'm guessing it's something old and potentially unsupported.

Comment: all you need is indexedDB

Comment: The broken link is WebSQL. It seems to be de facto obsolete.